# How to display a confirm dialog for h:commandLink

Tags: jsf

I have a h:commandLink and I want to display a confirm jsf dialog box before executing the action.(don't need the javascript confirm popup)

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myClass.downloadFile}" alt="Download File">
<div class='proceed' title="Download"></div>
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: If you don't want to use javascript, then you have to decide what kind of jsf framework's dialog you want to use. Richfaces, Primefaces, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use primefaces Confirm Dialog like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="ok" action="yourAction">
   <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
</p:commandButton>
```